# Xcode Interface Builder Height/Width Settings vs. View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how frame properties (height, width, posX, posY) work in terms of setting them in a View Controller vs on the Storyboard (Interface Builder).

For instance, let's say I have a `UICollectionView` object that I set to have a width of 400 and a height of 800. Then, in my code, I set the frame of that same object to 600 x 400. I haven't really found a consistent behavior. I tried setting the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it *sort of* worked - but it seem to 'jump' back and forth between that and what was set on the storyboard.

Basically my question is, when do the properties on the storyboard change the UI object? I assume that I just need to know that, and then reset them in the View Controller after the fact. Or, is there a way to set the height and width empty so that I can do it all in the code?

Any insight into this would be very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `AutoLayout` in your project then setting frames of the view objects you configured in storyboard won't work. Because after you set the frames, AutoLayout will update frames again which makes the frames set by you not working. If you want detail, you can check this article:[Advanced Auto Layout Tools](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html) But you can set frames of view objects created programmatically to position them.

You can check if you have turned on AutoLayout in you storyboard file's `file inspector`. There is one thing though, if you do want to use AutoLayout, be sure to not set view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. The default value of this property is `YES`. If you use AutoLayout, this property is set by storyboard for you, because constraints created in storyboard are enough to layout the views.

**EDIT:**

1) if you are not using AutoLayout then setting frames in code should work as expected.

2) yes you can, a little tricky though. you must create `UICollectionView` yourself using `[[UICollectionView alloc] init]` or load it from nib. and then configure cell in IB with a **xib** file. you can use AutoLayout to layout subviews of cell in **xib** file. and register the class of cell to `UICollectionView` or load cell object from nib yourself. then you should calculate the size of every cell and let AutoLayout layout subviews of cells.

although this is easier than layout interface entirely in code, it's still a little complicated. the better way is using AutoLayout. Since not all the layout detail can be done in the design time since some views' frame may be different depending on data. you can make a `basic` layout with AutoLayout first, then `IBOutlet` the constraints you want to configure on the fly. and change the `constant` property of constraint objects later. this way, you can 100% control the layout process and also let AutoLayout do the dirty jobs you don't want to do yourself. I suggest you read official docs of AutoLayout and other good resources about it.  The learning curve is steep at first, it may make you want to kill yourself too. But it's really powerful and easy to use. once you figured out how AutoLayout works, it will make your iOS development life much easier.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! Couple followup questions: (1) What if I'm not using AutoLayout - do the heights and widths that show on the storyboard take precedence over what is set dynamically in code? Or is it the other way around? (2) Can I use AutoLayout for some objects, and code for others. For example, I'd like to be able to code '100%' for the width and height for my `UICollectionView`, but then use AutoLayout for the table cells. All in the same view, but different objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the size of things through code, you could try creating outlets from the storyboard to the View Controller. Then in the View Controller, you can use `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` to set the size properties of your object(s). 
`viewDidLoad` will get called when that view is first created. `viewDidAppear` will get called each time that view comes back onto the screen (like if you are going back with a navigation controller).